# Is it possible to change the background color and back to the original in plain javascript every time i click a button?

Tags: javascript, background, background-color

I can't seem to see any results on google unless I use jQuery and I'm not so sure if jQuery and javascript plain work together.

Comment: Yes, should be possible. Can include `html` , `css` , `js` tried at Question ?

Comment: for clarification ... jQuery is a javascript library.that simplifies interacting with the dom ... so it will not conflict with any native script

Answer (score 0):

Try using `data-*` attribute to store color replacement, original background color of `button` element or `initial` setting; `JSON.parse()` , `JSON.stringify()` , `Array.prototype.reverse()` to toggle `data-*` attribute values that set `background` of `input type="button"` element; `onclick` event.

Not certain if requirement is to toggle background color, or reset to original color once ?

```html
<input type="button" value="button" data-colors='["blue", "buttonface"]' onclick="this.style.background = JSON.parse(this.dataset.colors)[0]; this.dataset.colors = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(this.dataset.colors).reverse());" />
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery will not conflict with javascript, it is just a js library :) So you can use the `selector.css()` of jquery or, in standard js i think it is `(element).style.background = color`.

I recommend using jQuery. Here is a SIMPLE jQuery way to do it:

```
  $("#button").click(function(){ 
   $("#tochange").css("background-color", "colorhex");
  });
```

If you want to swap colors you could, for example, add a variable.

```
var x;
$("#button").click(function(){
if(x==0){
    $("#tochange").css("background-color", "colorhex"); 
    x= 1;
 } 
 else{other way round} 
});
```