# Switch background color of a div between 2 colors on alternate clicks

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with ID "box". its initial background color is set to `#ff7700`. I want to create a function "function1()" to do following:

- first click: change the background color to `#ff0077`
- Second click: change the background color back to `#ff7700`
- third click: change the background color to `#ff0077`
- fourth click: change the background color back to `#ff7700`  and so on.

Code:

```
<style>
    #box{
    background-color: #ff7700;
    cursor: pointer;
}    
</style>

<div id="box" onClick="function1()" > Inner HTML</div>
```

I tried to write a function but it is not working.

```
<script>
    function function1(){
        var check = document.getElementById("box").style;
        check2=check.backgroundColor;
        if (check2 != "#ff0077"){
            check2="#ff7700";
            } else {
               check2="#ff0077";
            }
       }
</script>
```

please advise any other approach. I want to stick to core JS instead of using Jquery.

Answer (score 4):

It's better to use a boolean as toggle:

```js
var div = document.getElementById("box"),
    toggle = false;
    
div.onclick = function() {
  toggle = !toggle;                                     // invert toggle
  div.style.background = toggle? "#ff0077": "#ff7700";  // change background color depending on the value of toggle
}

div.style.background = "#ff7700";                       // give the div an initial background
```

```html
<div id="box">Inner HTML</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I did a simple example using jQuery. I hope I have helped.

Basically I get an element with class ".myDiv" and add a click event to it. Always the element is clicked the "toggleClass ()" method toggles the class.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".myDiv").bind("click", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("myClass");
  });
});
```

```css
.myDiv{
  padding: 1em;
  font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  background: #cccccc;
}

.myClass{
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda facere, cumque aliquam quis aut, velit quidem, repellendus quo maiores saepe unde sed reprehenderit laborum? Eum laborum possimus quidem, ea non.</p>
</div>

<!--jQuery Libary-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove `background-color: #ff7700;` from css selector `#box`
2. Create 2 css class, say `A` and `B` and put background colors there accordingly
3. Get the dom element `var domEl = document.getElementById("box");`
   After that if `domEl.className==="A"` then assign `"B"` to it,
   otherwise assign `"A"`

Answer (score 1):

`.style` property does not return a hexidecimal color code. You can use `window.getComputedStyle()` to get the computed `CSS` property, set the color to an `rgb()` value

```html
<style>
  #box {
    background-color: #ff7700;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>
<script>
  function function1() {
    if ( window.getComputedStyle(box).backgroundColor === "rgb(255, 119, 0)") {
      box.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 0, 119)";
    } else {
      box.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 119, 0)";
    }
  }
  onload = function() {
    const box = document.getElementById("box");
  }
</script>
<div id="box" onClick="function1()"> Inner HTML</div>
```

See also [Is it possible to change the background color and back to the original in plain javascript every time i click a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983488/is-it-possible-to-change-the-background-color-and-back-to-the-original-in-plain/34983635#34983635)

Answer (score 1):

You'll get the color of your element using [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) which will return your color to `rgb()` format. If you need to change your `rgb()` to `hex` learn more on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb).

**Here's an example**

```js
function function1(){
    var check = document.getElementById("box");
    var color = window.getComputedStyle(check, null).getPropertyValue('background-color');  
    if (color != "rgb(255, 119, 0)"){
      check.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 119, 0)";
    } else {
      check.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
    }
}
```

```css
#box{
    background-color: #ff7700;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onclick="function1()">Inner HTML</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using inline js code I'd suggest to pass the **this** variable: current element. In this way you don't need to select the element.

Using [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) and converting the value to an hexadecimal value your code is:

```js
function function1(ele) {
    var background = window.getComputedStyle(ele).backgroundColor;
    var hexColor = rgb2hex(background);
    if (hexColor != "#ff0077") {
        ele.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0077";
    } else {
        ele.style.backgroundColor = "#ff7700";
    }
}



function rgb2hex(rgb) {
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgba?[\s+]?\([\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?,[\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?,[\s+]?(\d+)[\s+]?/i);
    return (rgb && rgb.length === 4) ? "#" +
    ("0" + parseInt(rgb[1], 10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
    ("0" + parseInt(rgb[2], 10).toString(16)).slice(-2) +
    ("0" + parseInt(rgb[3], 10).toString(16)).slice(-2) : '';
}
```

```css
#box {
    background-color: #ff7700;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onClick="function1(this)"> Inner HTML</div>
```

Comment: All answers are perfect. for my project ibrahim mahrir's solutions works the best. thanks ibrahim mahrir